# Where can I find the Auger emission spectra of the most common chemical elements?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, spectroscopy

I am looking for an online resource where I can find the Auger emission spectra of (most common) chemical elements, i need them for AES (Auger Emission Spectroscopy). Thank you.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.uksaf.org/data/table.html)?

Comment: I think it should be good, if I am not wrong they are the main Auger emission peaks of all elements, right? I would like to have the whole spectra but this is a great step forward anyway, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, I just did a Google search of "Auger emission spectra data table" and it was in the first link that came up.

Comment: The Auger electrons come from outer shells so the energy does depend on the chemical bonding of the atom.

Comment: @MaxW - the question was for spectra _for elements_, not _elements in compounds_.

Comment: Note that the table Kyle found is for the [Auger parameter](http://www.xpsfitting.com/2012/08/auger-peaks-and-auger-parameter.html) which is not the peak position of the spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

NIST has a very comprehensive listing. You can start at [this link](http://srdata.nist.gov/xps/all_dat_el.aspx), then click on an individual element. For example, for Lithium you would get [the following table](http://srdata.nist.gov/xps/query_all_dat_el.aspx?elm1=Li) :

[image]

It's easy to see how the address is constructed, and how you could generate such a table for each element: `http://srdata.nist.gov/xps/query_all_dat_el.aspx?elm1=Li`

Just change `elm1=Li` to whatever element you want...

Comment: It seems good... Is there a way to separate Auger peaks from the others (such as photoelectron lines) without clicking on each line?